# Multi camera render addon issue

Tags: add-on

I wanted to render at 1 click all setup cameras. So i found the addon Multicamera Render from [here](https://github.com/lapineige/Blender_add-ons/blob/master/Multi-Camera-Render/multi_camera_render_v2.py)

With the camera selected in the render tab with the multicamera render button

[image]

I click but there is no respond or no process bar and blender hang. Is this the correct way im using the addon or some other method. Is there any other addon or this will work fine. Multi camera Render at one click

Comment: If you want to switch cameras in the scene there is an easy way without using addons at all. Select your camera, Hit Ctrl+0 (to make it the actual camera) and choose the frame you want the camera to start. Then hover over the timeline, hit "M" to add a marker, then Ctrl+B to bind the camera to the marker. Apply these steps on all cameras and you should have the same result as with the addon quite easily (To remove markers select them and hit "X" as usual).

Comment: @NGCHunter2 for im not getting the progress bar author replied me The only way to see the progress is to open Blender console (on Windows: (Blender menu) Windows > Show System Console. On Linux you need to open Blender from a console) - this way is useful to be sure it started correctly - or to check on the final repo is the images are present - to know if it finished correctly. Im not getting what does he mean to see in blender console

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I downloaded and "installed from file" this script in 2.79:

https://raw.githubusercontent.com/lapineige/Blender_add-ons/master/Multi-Camera-Render/multi_camera_render_v2-1.py

Then, selected both (2) cameras and pressed the "multiple camera render" and it produced 2 images, as expected.

[image]

With the addon default settings (empty directory) those images were created in the blender folder itself (I use a zip blender version); selecting a folder on my desktop as "directory" they were created in that folder, as expected...

[image]

Comment: I have a model which took 15min to render for single camera. With the addon Im not getting the progress bar and it stuck so the author of the addon reply me The only way to see the progress is to open Blender console (on Windows: (Blender menu) Windows > Show System Console. On Linux you need to open Blender from a console) - this way is useful to be sure it started correctly - or to check on the final repo is the images are present - to know if it finished correctly. Can you plz show me how can i see the progress bar i did no get from his reply what he mean