# Assign camera to renderlayer

Tags: rendering, camera, render-layers

Is there a workaround to assign a camera to a renderlayer?

I have multiple renderlayers (each with a different part of the scene). I would like to combine them into a single rendered multilayer exr. But I want to render each layer with a specific camera assign to the respective part of the scene.

I all else fails I will write a script to loop through the layers, activate a camera, render the image, save it and at the end combine the layers via the compositor. Or does a builtin method exist already?

I'm using Blender Internal with freestlyle and transparency.

Related: [multiple camera renders into multiple images](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/96327/multi-camera-render-addon-issue)

Answer (score 5):

As far as I know there can only be one active camera per scene
But you can make different scenes, each one with it's active camera and its own render layers..

To save resources, make a new scene linking data, then select an other camera as the active one for the new scene.

Mix both scenes in the compositor.

[image]

Comment: That's awesome, is there a way to copy/update settings from one scene to another after I created the duplicate, specifically Freestyle lineset settings or Simplify settings?

Comment: There is a *Copy Settings Addon* shipped with blender @Leander. Does that work in your case?

Comment: @p2or This sounds promising, but I can't find a way to copy the freestyle line set settings (slots)? Do you know how it works and how one could add that functionality? (Before I start looking through the addons code.)

Comment: You can enable *Line Thickness* as well as [simplify settings](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XT8WA.jpg) (from the list) in your main scene, then press *copy render settings* to the desired scenes below @Leander